# Give an example of a non-Abelian group that has exactly four elements of order 10.

Tags: group-theory

Give an example of a non-Abelian group that has exactly four elements of order 10.

Would $D_{10}$ still work even though its not cyclic? I know that since $10$ is a positive divisor of $20$ the number of elements of order $10$ in a cyclic group of order $20$ is $\phi(10)=4$

Is there a better approach to find non-abelian groups with exactly $k$ elements of order $d$?

Comment: There can be exactly four elements of order 10 because any element $a$ of order 10 has its generated set $\langle a\rangle$ having exactly 4 generators: $a$, $a^3$, $a^7$, $a^9$.

Comment: So in this case there is actually only one cyclic subgroup of order 10.

Comment: "even though its not cyclic" any cyclic group would be abelian, so it is actually required that the group is not cyclic.

Comment: How about taking the product of $Z_{10}$ with a suitable non-Abelian group?

Comment: "Is there a better approach...." Define "better". The comment immediately preceding this one suggests finding an abelian group with exactly $k$ elements of order $d$, and then taking the direct product with some non-abelian group chosed so as to produce no additional elements of order $d$.

Comment: I am finding the comments confusing! The answer to your question is yes, $D_{10}$ (dihedral group of order $20$) works.